# Issue with multiple buttons action in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created buttons using a for loop with different tags in objective c, but problem is that it doesn't call BtnClick function except for first 2-3 button clicks. Any help will be appreciated.

```
for(int i = 0; i<40; i++) 
{ 
   UIButton butContinue...  
   btnContinue.tag=i; 
    [btnContinue setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] 
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    btnContinue.autoresizingMask=YES; 
    [btnContinue addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(clickBtn_Continue:)     
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}
```

Comment: did you checked size of button frame? If it is small, your initial touches might be out side button !!! I think so.

Comment: My code is:for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)
{
btnContinue.tag=i;

[btnContinue setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



btnContinue.autoresizingMask=YES;
  
[btnContinue addTarget:self action:@selector(clickBtn_Continue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

Comment: And I added images to buttons so i can click specific buttons here.But now action is called here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Loop the code to create buttons**

```
 UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [yourButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
 [yourButton setTitle:@"Click Here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 yourButton.tag = tag;
 [self.view addSubview:yourButton];
 //increment x or y as per your need,
```

**Action something like**

```
- (IBAction) yourAction : (UIButton *) sender
{
      NSLog(@"I'm %d pressed.",sender.tag);
}
```

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh, If the code is same then it should working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please also set frame  dynamically. In this code it will added 40 buttons on same frame. Initialize
 button with alloc init. So it will not autorelease. use below
UIButton* yourButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]; // And set frame dynamically